# How to merge a number of loops into one in a VBA program?

Tags: vba, loops, while-loop, do-loops

I am fairly inexperienced with VBA, and I can't figure out how to make this loop. I set up 4 separate statements and it works this way, but I want to make this one statement.

```
i = 1
Do Until i > combos
        Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i + Defrepeat - 1, 10)) = Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 4))
i = i + TErepeat
Loop

w = 4
Do Until w > combos
        Range(Cells(w, 10), Cells(w + Defrepeat - 1, 10)) = Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(4, 4))
w = w + TErepeat
Loop

p = 7
Do Until p > combos
        Range(Cells(p, 10), Cells(p + Defrepeat - 1, 10)) = Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, 4))
p = p + TErepeat
Loop

k = 10
Do Until k > combos
        Range(Cells(k, 10), Cells(k + Defrepeat - 1, 10)) = Range(Cells(6, 4), Cells(6, 4))
k = k + TErepeat
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim c As Range, i As Long, n As Long

Set c = Cells(3, 4)

For n = 1 To 10 Step 3
    i = n
    Do Until i > combos
        Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i + Defrepeat - 1, 10)) = c.Value
        i = i + TErepeat
    Loop
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
Next n
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim. There seems to be a problem starting with the second loop though. I'm getting an error message: "Run-time error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error." It ran through the first time and worked, but the second loop didn't work.